# Android: close connection only when Activity should be destroyed

Tags: android, orientation-changes

I have an Activity which connects the the server inside onCreate method. Because the connection must stay opened even when I rotate screen I store its reference to the static variable.

Example:

```
public class Main extends Activity 
{
   protected static MyConnector connector;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      if (connector == null)
      {
         connector = new MyConnector();
      }
   }
}
```

The connection must stay opened if I open another activity from Main but if I close the Main activity it should be closed.

The problem that I have is I don't know when/how to close the connection. If I close it inside onDestroy it will be destroyed if I rotate screen because the activity is recreated when the orientation changes. If I close it on activity focus it would be closed when I go to the next activity. So... I would like to close it only when I don't need the Main activity and I would like to destroy it for ever.

How would you do that? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [onConfigChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) to retain your Activity when Orientation is changed. This way onDestroy() will be called only when the user exits the Activity.

Check [Handling the Configuration Change Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)(at the bottom of the page) to see how to use [onConfigChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29).

**onConfigChanged**

*"If your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific configuration change and **you have a performance limitation that requires you to avoid the Activity restart**, then you can declare that your Activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your Activity."*

Comment: Yeah... I thought about that but... what about if you have more than one object. Then you must somehow returned an array or smth.